# bind to nested separate service

Tags: android, service, process, nested

assume has an app."myapp".
an service in separate process."myservice".
    process=":myservice".
an second service in separated service. "secondservice".

```
process=":myservice".
```

two service are
    exported = "true".

```
inputPinCodeIntent = new Intent(context, EnterCodeActivity.class);
inputPinCodeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(inputPinCodeIntent);
```

in EnterCodeActivity get an code and with

```
Messenger messenger = new Messenger();
messenger.send(m);
```

send an message to "secondservice".
but dont gotted message.
im running service like

```
final Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, PincodeCreditionalInput.class);
bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

in "onStart" event.
anyone can help?

thankful.